# How to place a value inside a text area

Tags: html, odoo, render

How can I place a value inside a Textarea HTML tag in the Odoo website template views?
The code I have below is not working in every case scenario, I want the text area to show a value if there is an existing value inside the project field if not then there shouldn't be a value inside the text area. I also noticed that the t-field returns the saved data in the database as rendered HTML content which is also an issue because if the data has a new line then the content inside the text area contains HTML tags e.g instead
of new line `<br>` is shown as a value inside the text area.

```
<textarea class="form-control textarea-resize new_project_job_description"
                                                  id="project_job_description"
                                                  name="project_job_description"
                                                  t-field="project_job_description or project.job_description"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with odoo, but can you achieve the same with it like you would in standard HTML `<textarea>Values Here</textarea>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea class="form-control textarea-resize new_project_job_description"
                                              id="project_job_description"
                                              name="project_job_description">
    <t t-esc="project.job_description"/>
</textarea>
```